# How to set score google play game services as time format?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, google-play-games

I have tested to submit a score in a time format not integer but when I open the leaderboard I got my score show like this format 0.03  whereas  when I created the leaderboard in gpgs it shows the format should be 00:00:00 ?any idea why I am seeing the time like that..

when I send 75 seconds which suppose to be in this format 00:01:15 --> I got 0.08 in gpgs leaderboard.

note: I am using corona sdk + lua

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For others who come across this, Google expects the time to be in milliseconds. Simply multiply the score by 1000 and it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that goes for all their kind of scores